# Node.js good-console preventing particular logs

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, hapi.js

So as of now, I have the following items being logged to the node console:

```
events: { log: '*', response: '*', error: '*' }
```

I am successfully receiving the expected logs in the console, although I would like to limit the response logs.

For example: I will get 304 response logs when you navigate between pages in the web page as well as 200 response logs when reading from tables in the DB.  Is it possible to disable the 304 logs?

Comment: What logging tool are you using that logs responses?

Comment: My assumption was the good-console plugin.  I've had very little to do with the instance of node that I'm working on so my knowledge is still very limited on how it all works.

I see here

https://github.com/hapijs/good 
that you can limit logs in general like this 
events: { log: ['error', 'medium'] }

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found some type of a work around to my issue.  My main issue was to just limit the logs that would hit the node console to make debugging a little easier by limiting the types of responses I would receive.  Any time my web page would access either an html, css, js, txt, png or any other file, it would hit the node console.

I went into the good-console plugin lib/index.js and added a conditional statement for eventNames == 'response'

Basically I look at the file type on the path and exclude the push statement for any logs with the particular file types mentioned above, as well as any others that may come up in the future.